# Can the object file name be changed from .obj during cmake compiler testing?

Tags: cmake

Ultimately, I'm trying to build Apache QPID to run in the HPE NonStop OSS environment (a Posix-like environment on the NonStop system).  The latest version of QPID uses cmake to build so I first need to get cmake to work for that environment.  My earlier attempts tried to build in OSS directly (I needed to build cmake first before trying to build QPID), but I ran into many problems there.  So lately I'm trying to build in Windows using a set of cross-development tools (compilers etc.) for NonStop.  I've downloaded a Windows version of cmake 2.8 (suggested by the QPID build instructions) and am trying to use that with the X-dev tools to build QPID for OSS.

One big issue I've run into has to do with how cmake does things to test compilers and so forth early on.  It will invoke the compiler to create an intermediate object file from C (and/or C++) source file and after that it will invoke the compiler to link an object file from the intermediate file.  It seems that cmake prefers to add .obj to file names to create the intermediate object file name.  This will work OK with my cross-compiler when creating the file (the name passed with -o to the compiler) but it will **not** work when passing this name for link purposes.  Here is a short bit of the output per the CMakeError.log file (from trying build an OSS version of cmake 2.8 itself):

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Source/cmake-2.8.0/bld/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:/cygwin/bin/make.exe "cmTryCompileExec/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Source/cmake-2.8.0/bld/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:/Source/cmake-2.8.0/bld/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
/cygdrive/c/NonStop/tndm_cmplrs-j20/usr/bin/c89.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:/Source/cmake-2.8.0/bld/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec
/cygdrive/c/NonStop/tndm_cmplrs-j20/usr/bin/c89.exe        "CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj"   -o cmTryCompileExec
c89.exe: error: Invalid input file extension"CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj".
```

The cross-compiler fails because it **requires** intermediate object files to use .o for the extension, in order to determine they are intermediate object files.  There is no way to get the c89 compiler to recognize testCCompiler.c.obj as a file type it knows what to do with.

So I've been searching (trying to find a local expert, but no one in my organization knows cmake; also numerous Google searches but could not find an answer) to see if there is any way to get cmake to change the name of the output file it uses for these type of compiles and tests.  I've found info and then set CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION in a toolchain file:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".o")
```

but that has made no difference.

If I can find a way to get cmake to create object files with names like testCCompiler.c.o instead of testCCompiler.c.obj, then the c89 cross-compiler would work.

Is it possible to do this?

---

UPDATE:  I've managed to figure out that setting CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION in the toolchain file doesn't help.  This gets overwritten in the CMakeCInformation.cmake (depending on whether UNIX is set or not).  I also tracked down that UNIX gets set to true in Platform/UnixPaths.cmake, which gets INCLUDEd by various Platform files.  So I've created a Modules/Platform/OSS.cmake file which includes it to takes care of that.  I'll probably need/want to add other settings there later as I determine more flags for compilers etc that should be set to specific values for the OSS environment.

Comment: Probably, setting [CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_LANG_OUTPUT_EXTENSION.html) variable should resolve your problem.

Comment: I've added the following to my toolchain file:  
  
    SET(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".o")  
  
but it makes no difference here.

Comment: This variable affects only on "C" sources, for C++ `CXX` lang prefix should be used. It is difficult to resolve the problem without viewing your code.

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior **long** before it ever gets to the code itself.  (And the code isn't mine, per se; I'm just trying to get cmake on Windows to build itself for Nonstop.)  At the point of the failure (just trying test compiles) the test code is C.  Here's sample output (stripped down for size):  

Building C object testCCompiler.c.obj
c89.exe -o testCCompiler.c.obj -c testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec
c89.exe testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTryCompileExec
c89.exe: error: Invalid input file extension"testCCompiler.c.obj".  

cmake decides to use .obj as the extension here.

Comment: The better place for build output is your **question post**. On Stack Overflow it is completely legal to edit the question post every time you want to provide additional information about the problem. Also content of toolchain file could be interesting (lines, where you set compiler and `CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION` variable). Also add version of CMake you use.

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated the post now.